# Tomcat - Deploying application - datasource issue

Tags: java, tomcat, jhipster

I have one tomcat container and two web applications (jhipster applications). First one is only for front-end part and second one is for back-end.

On tomcat I have two webapps folders - `webapps` and `webapps2`. When I tried to deploy front-end application in webapps2 folder I'm getting an error:

```
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-0)] with key 'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:792) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5623) [catalina.jar:7.0.72]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:7.0.72]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [catalina.jar:7.0.72]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [catalina.jar:7.0.72]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [catalina.jar:7.0.72]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092) [catalina.jar:7.0.72]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984) [catalina.jar:7.0.72]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

I have register two services, back-end part works on 8080 port and front-end part on 7070. I know that the best option is to deploy front-end application on apache web server but in that case I will need to single out application from jhipster project but I don't have time for that.

Does anyone have an idea what happened here and how to fix this issue?

Just to notice that if I use two tomcat servers everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot comment so I do an answer.

This seems to be the problem.
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-0)] with key 'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.**InstanceAlreadyExistsException**: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource

There seems to be an conflict in that both apps use the same name. Probably two beans with same name datasource.

Comment: Well I would go into the two webapps and check my datasource settings, but I see that this has been discussed previously on stackoverflow, check here if you need more help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440985/unable-to-register-mbean-hikaridatasource-hikaripool-0-with-key-datasource

Comment: yes, it has sense... Those two applications use same bean name.

Comment: I have changed method dataSource in DatabaseConfiguration.class to dataSource2 and my application works fine.